# SonataAdminBundle and ACL Class-scope Permissions

Tags: acl, sonata-admin

Sorry for my english...

In my project I use ACL with SonataAdminBundle, but I can not understand why they did so, you need to have to create a record in the database, even when I want to use only Class-scope without Object-scope.

Also, when you create, for example, comments, SonataAdminBundle automatically creates an entry in acl_object_identities, it clutters up this action database.

I created a role that has the right to full access to all records in a table, regardless of who created the records, but SonataAdminBundle only displays them and prohibits editing.
The documentation for SonataAdminBundle reads:

> because the object ACL permission is checked, the ACL for the object
>   must have been created, otherwise the AclVoter will deny EDIT access
>   for a non super admin user trying to edit another non super admin
>   user. This is automatically done when the object is created using the
>   Admin. If objects are also created outside the Admin, have a look at
>   the createSecurityObject method in the AclSecurityHandler.

But why? How to avoid this?

Do not want to write hooks.

Thank you in advance for any comments and help on this.

Comment: currently replaced service "security.acl.voter.class", disabled JMSSecurityExtraBundle() and written the hook
if (null !== $this->logger) {
                    $this->logger->debug('No ACL found for the object identity. Voting to deny access.');
                }

//                return self::ACCESS_DENIED;
                // hook fixme
                return self::ACCESS_GRANTED;

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the object ACLs with `php app/console sonata:admin:generate-object-acl`